# How do I minimize all active forms in my application using VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, minimize

How do I minimize all active forms in my application with a single button click?

I have multiple forms visible at a time, and I want all my active forms to minimize when I click on a single button on one of the forms.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey anybody know Why in the bottom right corner of my question, there is a box which shows my user name and below that 126, 7 and then 100%. What are these numbers for ?

Comment: LOL, I didn't know I get reputation scores for asking questions. So  can I exchange my points for prizes ?

Comment: Are you talking about MDI child windows?

Comment: No, I am not using MDI Child windows

Comment: @abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz Yes, if you consider moderator privileges as prizes, sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not trying to minimize MDI child windows, you can simply loop through all of the open forms in your application and set their [`WindowState` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) to "Minimized". VB.NET provides an [`OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) collection for your [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y6135ed.aspx) class that makes this mind-blowingly simple.

Place the following sample code into the `Click` event handler of a button control, or similar method:

```
For Each frm As Form in Application.OpenForms
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
Next frm
```

If you want to minimize all of the forms when the user clicks the *system* minimize box on the title bar of a single form, you will need to listen in on that event, and execute the above code. Do this by overriding the `OnSizeChanged` method for each form whose minimize events you want to apply to all open forms.

You could also cause all of your forms to restore to the normal state whenever one of them is restored by clicking on its taskbar icon. Just reverse the same procedure used to minimize the windows, specifying a "Normal" window state instead of "Minimized".

For example, you might write the following code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnSizeChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Call the base class first
    MyBase.OnSizeChanged(e)

    ' See if this form was just minimized
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        ' Minimize all open forms
        For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        Next frm
    ElseIf Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
        ' Restore all open forms
        For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Next frm
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That was great but there is one more problem, I want all my forms to go to normal state when I click any one of the forms minimized in the taskbar.

Comment: @abcd: Hoo boy. That's certainly possible; give me a minute to update my answer.

Comment: Muhahah...it works.  @Cody Thanks a lot, I learn a lot each time I get an answer. Don't know much about levels , how many levels are there ?

Comment: @abcd: Yeah, you can go a lot lower than what the .NET Framework normally exposes to you. It's often called P/Invoking, short for platform invoking, but all it means is that you're calling *native* Windows API functions, rather than their managed counterparts provided by the *managed* .NET Framework environment. It's often necessary when the functionality you want isn't provided by .NET. But I updated my answer after some testing; it looks like the .NET designers got it right and `OnSizeChanged` isn't called needlessly. No reason to overcomplicate things unless you have an actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the Application.Forms collection like so.

```
For Each form as Form in Application.OpenForms
     .....
End For
```

Does this help?